# Laplace transform with expanded limits

Tags: laplace-transform

> Evaluate $L\{F(t)\}$ if
> $$ F(t) = \begin{cases} \sin(t-\pi/3), &t> \pi/3 \\ 0, & t <\pi/3. \end{cases}$$

I'm stuck on this question on Laplace Transforms.

I've broken the limits from $0$ to $\pi/3$ and from $\pi/3$ to infinity. The term with limit $0$ to $\pi/3$ zeroes out. I'm on a stalemate with the second term with limit $\pi/3$ to infinity.

Comment: The integral
$$\int_{\pi/3}^{\infty} \sin(t-\pi/3)e^{-st}~dt$$
can be solved using integration by parts twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be re-written using the unit step function
$$u(t)=
\begin{cases}
1,&t\ge 0\\
0,&t<0
\end{cases}
$$
as
$$F(t)=\sin(t-\pi/3)\,u(t-\pi/3).$$
Then can you finish with the time-shifting property:
$$L[f(t-a)\,u(t-a)]=e^{-as}\,L[f(t)]$$
and the LT of the $\sin$ function:
$$L[\sin(t)]=\frac{1}{s^2+1}?$$